# reverse order when comparing local and remote files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm currently using Eclipse Juno as my IDE for C/C++ development, and it has a nice compare tool built-in, but it really bothers me that the local (modified) version of the file is displayed on the left side, instead of the right side, like on most diff tools.

I've looked through all preferences in Eclipse related to compare/patch but couldn't find anything.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Thanks,
Claudiu